Why does array?.length still warn that the array might be undefined?
Given this code:
interface Obj {
  array?: string[]
}

function fuu(obj: Obj) {
  const { array } = obj
  if (array?.length >= 1) {
    // ...
  }
}

Why would it still say 'array.length' is possibly 'undefined'.
When the whole purpose of the ? is to check if it's undefined or not.
I'm assuming it's because the operator >= 1 needs a defined value.
Is there a way other than doing:
if (array && array?.length >=1), or const { array = [] } = obj?

Because it is? If array is undefined, then so is array?.length. Optional chaining prevents the error, but the value still ends up undefined - it's basically (array !== null && array !== undefined) ? array.length : undefined. And yes there are other ways (e.g. array?.length ?? -1), but which is appropriate depends on context.

This question essentially contains the answer; undefined >= 1 is considered an error in TS, so you need to do something like (array && array.length >=1) or const {array=[]} = obj. Why do you need another way? There doesn't seem to be much motivation for an answer here.

The comments are right, the answer is in the question.
Either
if (array && array?.length >=1)
or
const { array = [] } = obj
Are sufficient alternatives.
